# Is it a good practice to modify a component's state and then call "setState(this.state)"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS.

I have a stateful component (stopwatch container) and multiple child components which are stateless (stopwatches).

In the outer component, I'm doing something like this:

```
// the outer component is a "container" for multiple stopwatches
tick: function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.stopwatches.length; i++)
    {
      // if a particular stopwatch is "started", I'll increase it's time
      if (this.state.stopwatches[i].status == "started")
        {
          this.state.stopwatches[i].time.seconds++;
          // do some processing
        }
    }
  // this is the suspicious code!
  this.setState(this.state);
}
```

Notice that I'm changing the `this.state` property and then calling `setState()` on the `state` object itself. This seems so wrong to me. But, in the other hand, in order to **not** manipulate the `state` object itself, i'd have to clone it and then do `setState(stateClone)`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to clone objects effectively in JS, neither if I really should do this.

Can I continue to do `setState(this.state)` ?

Comment: if you aren't facing some side-effects from doing what you're doing, then it should be fine.

Comment: Actually I'm asking if it's a good practice from the ReactJS perspective. Maybe there's better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling `this.setState(this.state)` you can just call [`this.forceUpdate()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate).

Just remember that this is not recommended way of updating components state. If you are unsure about your modifications take a look on [Immutability Helpers](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents here: React will re-render every time you call `setState`:

```
boolean shouldComponentUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState)
```

returns `true` by default. If you don't wish to re-render make `shouldComponentUpdate(object nextProps, object nextState)` to return `false`.

Quoting from Facebook docs:

> By default, `shouldComponentUpdate` always returns `true` to prevent
> subtle bugs when `state` is mutated in place, but if you are careful
> to always treat `state` as immutable and to read only from `props` and
> `state` in `render()` then you can override `shouldComponentUpdate`
> with an implementation that compares the old `props` and `state` to
> their replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from immutability (which is always good), the second best would be `this.setState({stopwatches: this.state.stopwatches})`.

With immutability helpers, it'd look like this:

```
var stopwatches = this.state.stopwatches.map(function(watch){
  return update(watch, {
    time: {$set: watch.time + 1}
  });
});
this.setState({stopwatches: stopwatches})
```

Or with es6 you can save a few characters.

```
var stopwatches = this.state.stopwatches.map(watch => update(watch, {
    time: {$set: watch.time + 1}
});
this.setState({stopwatches})
```