# Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that React tutorials and documentation warn in [no uncertain terms](https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c#.24f7t0qpz) that state should not be directly mutated and that everything should go through `setState`.

I would like to understand why, exactly, I can't just directly change state and then (in the same function) call `this.setState({})` just to trigger the `render`.

E.g.: The below code seems to work just fine:

```js
const React = require('react');

const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      some: {
        rather: {
          deeply: {
            embedded: {
              stuff: 1,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
  updateCounter: function () {
    this.state.some.rather.deeply.embedded.stuff++;
    this.setState({}); // just to trigger the render ...
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        Counter value: {this.state.some.rather.deeply.embedded.stuff}
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={this.updateCounter}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  },
});

export default App;
```

I am all for following conventions but I would like to enhance my further understanding of how ReactJS actually works and what can go wrong or is it sub-optimal with the above code.

The notes under the [`this.setState` documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) basically identify two gotchas:

1. That if you mutate state directly and then subsequently call `this.setState` this may replace (overwrite?) the mutation you made. I don't see how this can happen in the above code.
2. That `setState` may mutate `this.state` effectively in an asynchronous / deferred way and so when accessing `this.state` right after calling `this.setState` you are not guaranteed to access the final mutated state. I get that, by this is not an issue if `this.setState` is the last call of the update function.

Comment: Check the [notes under `setState` documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). It covers some of the good reasons.

Comment: @Kujira I updated my question to also address the notes you mentioned.

Comment: beside the fact that you think you can control it, you are simply short-circuiting a framework's workflow. Javascript allows you to do that, just keep in mind that once you break the pattern, the framework is no more responsible for your state's consistency.

Comment: It's not a matter of "can't" mutate state directly, it's a matter of "shouldn't".

Comment: Strange, this was asked 4 months ago and still no accepted answer, is this such a difficult question to answer ? I cannot really find an answer to this using google...

Comment: I asked a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213254/reacts-setstate-data-mutation-for-nested-structures-why-not-modify-state-di?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: then it become Anuglar1.

Comment: It's really simple when you think about it. React is called "react" because it needs to react to something changing. Javascript has no built-in ability to have property assignments be observable/react-to-able. Because of this, the setState API was created to allow observability, and all react-to-able assignments must always be done through that.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[The React docs for `setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) have this to say:

> *NEVER* mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.
>
> `setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.
>
> `setState()` will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`. If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`, calling `setState()` only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Basically, if you modify `this.state` directly, you create a situation where those modifications might get overwritten.

Related to your extended questions 1) and 2), `setState()` is not immediate. **It queues a state transition based on what it thinks is going on which may not include the direct changes to `this.state`**. Since it's queued rather than applied immediately, it's entirely possible that something is modified in between such that your direct changes get overwritten.

If nothing else, you might be better off just considering that not directly modifying `this.state` can be seen as good practice. You may know personally that your code interacts with React in such a way that these over-writes or other issues can't happen but you're creating a situation where other developers or future updates can suddenly find themselves with weird or subtle issues.

Comment: "It queues a state transition based on what it thinks is going on which may not include the direct changes to this.state. Since it's queued rather than applied immediately, it's entirely possible that something is modified in between such that your direct changes get overwritten."
Could you please elaborate on what you mean by this ? Give an example where this is a problem ?

Comment: @jhegedus [Dive into React codebase: Handling state changes](http://reactkungfu.com/2016/03/dive-into-react-codebase-handling-state-changes/) goes into extreme detail on how the `setState()` and callback systems work and gives you good idea of why there would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ouroborus!

Comment: Upvoted because of this: "It queues a state transition based on what it thinks is going on which may not include the direct changes to this.state"

Answer (score 153):

### This answer is to provide enough information to not change/mutate the state directly in React.

React follows [**Unidirectional Data Flow**](https://hashnode.com/post/why-does-react-emphasize-on-unidirectional-data-flow-and-flux-architecture-ciibz8ej600n2j3xtxgc0n1f0). Meaning, the data flow inside react should and will be expected to be in a circular path.

**React's Data flow without flux**

[image]

To make React work like this, developers made React similar to **functional programming**. The rule of thumb of functional programming is **immutability**. Let me explain it loud and clear.

**How does the unidirectional flow works?**

- `states` are a data store which contains the data of a component.
- The `view` of a component renders based on the state.
- When the `view` needs to change something on the screen, that value should be supplied from the `store`.
- To make this happen, React provides `setState()` function which takes in an `object` of new `states` and does a compare and merge(similar to `object.assign()`) over the previous state and adds the new state to the state data store.
- Whenever the data in the state store changes, react will trigger an re-render with the new state which the `view` consumes and shows it on the screen.

This cycle will continue throughout the component's lifetime.

If you see the above steps, it clearly shows a lot of things are happening behind when you change the state. So, when you mutate the state directly and call `setState()` with an empty object. The `previous state` will be polluted with your mutation. Due to which, the shallow compare and merge of two states will be disturbed or won't happen, because you'll have only one state now. This will disrupt all the React's Lifecycle Methods.

As a result, your app will behave abnormal or even crash. Most of the times, it won't affect your app because all the apps which we use for testing this are pretty small.

And another downside of mutation of `Objects` and `Arrays` in JavaScript is, when you assign an object or an array, you're just making a reference of that object or that array. When you mutate them, all the reference to that object or that array will be affected. React handles this in a intelligent way in the background and simply give us an API to make it work.

**Most common errors done when handling states in React**

```
// original state
this.state = {
  a: [1,2,3,4,5]
}

// changing the state in react
// need to add '6' in the array

// bad approach
const b = this.state.a.push(6)
this.setState({
  a: b
})
```

In the above example, `this.state.a.push(6)` will mutate the state directly. Assigning it to another variable and calling `setState` is same as what's shown below. As we mutated the state anyway, there's no point assigning it to another variable and calling `setState` with that variable.

```
// same as 
this.state.a.push(6)
this.setState({})
```

Many people do this. **This is so wrong**. This breaks the beauty of React and is bad programming practice.

So, what's the best way to handle states in React? Let me explain.

When you need to change 'something' in the existing state, first get a copy of that 'something' from the current state.

```
// original state
this.state = {
  a: [1,2,3,4,5]
}

// changing the state in react
// need to add '6' in the array

// create a copy of this.state.a
// you can use ES6's destructuring or loadash's _.clone()
const currentStateCopy = [...this.state.a]
```

Now, mutating `currentStateCopy` won't mutate the original state. Do operations over `currentStateCopy` and set it as the new state using `setState()`.

```
currentStateCopy.push(6)
this.setState({
  a: currentStateCopy
})
```

This is beautiful, right?

By doing this, all the references of `this.state.a` won't get affected until we use `setState`. This gives you control over your code and this'll help you write elegant test and make you confident about the performance of the code in production.

To answer your question,

> Why can't I directly modify a component's state?

---

**Well, you can**. But, you need to face the following consequences.

1. When you scale, you'll be writing unmanageable code.
2. You'll lose control of `state` across components.
3. Instead of using React, you'll be writing custom codes over React.

**Immutability is not a necessity because JavaScript is single threaded, but it's a good to follow practices which will help you in the long run.**

<sup>*PS. I've written about 10000 lines of mutable React JS code. If it breaks now, I don't know where to look into because all the values are mutated somewhere. When I realized this, I started writing immutable code. Trust me! That's the best thing you can do it to a product or an app.*</sup>

Comment: Just a reminder: most basic methods for cloning in JS (`slice`, ES6 destructuring, etc.) are shallow. If you have a nested array or nested objects you'll need to look at other methods of deep copying, e.g. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` (though this particular method won't work if your object has circular references).

Comment: @Galen Long would [`_.cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#cloneDeep) suffice

Comment: @JoshBroadhurst Great point, yes it would. And if anyone's worried about installing the entire Lodash package for just one function, you can install just the cloneDeep module with `npm install lodash.clonedeep` and use it with `let cloneDeep = require("lodash.clonedeep");`.

Comment: Pranesh, a great answer. For subsequent readers, in the first code example at the line, `const b = this.state.a.push(6)` constant b holds a value of **6** as **Array.prototype.push()** would return the **new length** of the array and not the array itself. So keep that in mind. Further when `this.setState({a: b})` is executed, the `state.a` is definitely pointing to a "number" (value) type instead of the previous "array" (reference) type. So that has changed, however the reference to `state` object itself  doesn't change, hence we have mutated the state.

Comment: Like wrote @SudhansuChoudhary, for the first example, we can have: 
```const b = this.state.a;
b.push(6);
this.setState({a: b});```

Answer (score 10):

the simplest answer to "

> Why can't I directly modify a component's state:

is all about **Updating phase.**

when we update the state of a component all it's children are going to be rendered as well. or our entire component tree rendered.

but when i say our entire component tree is rendered that doesn’t mean that the entire DOM is updated.
when a component is rendered we basically get a react element, so that is updating our virtual dom.

React will then look at the virtual DOM, it also has a copy of the old virtual DOM, **that is why we shouldn’t update the state directly**, so we can have two different object references in memory, we have the old virtual DOM as well as the new virtual DOM.

then react will figure out what is changed and based on that it will update the real DOM accordingly .

hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

It surprises me that non of the current answers talk about pure/memo components ([`React.PureComponent`](https://react.dev/reference/react/PureComponent) or [`React.memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo)). These components only re-render when a change in one of the props is detected.

Say you mutate state directly and pass, not the value, but the over coupling object to the component below. This object still has the same reference as the previous object, meaning that pure/memo components won't re-render, even though you mutated one of the properties.

Since you don't always know what type of component you are working with when importing them from libraries, this is yet another reason to stick to the non-mutating rule.

Here is an example of this behaviour in action (using [`R.evolve`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) to simplify creating a copy and updating nested content):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { some: { rather: { deeply: { nested: { stuff: 1 } } } } };
  
  mutatingIncrement = () => {
    this.state.some.rather.deeply.nested.stuff++;
    this.setState({});
  }
  nonMutatingIncrement = () => {
    this.setState(R.evolve(
      { some: { rather: { deeply: { nested: { stuff: n => n + 1 } } } } }
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Normal Component: <CounterDisplay {...this.state} />
        <br />
        Pure Component: <PureCounterDisplay {...this.state} />
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.mutatingIncrement}>mutating increment</button>
        <button onClick={this.nonMutatingIncrement}>non-mutating increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const CounterDisplay = (props) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    Counter value: {props.some.rather.deeply.nested.stuff}
  </React.Fragment>
);
const PureCounterDisplay = React.memo(CounterDisplay);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ramda@0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid every time to create a copy of `this.state.element` you can use [update](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#update) with `$set or $push` or many others from [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)

e.g.:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const newData = update(myData, {
  x: {y: {z: {$set: 7}}},
  a: {b: {$push: [9]}}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setState trigger re rendering of the components.when we want to update state again and again we must need to setState otherwise it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score -2):

My current understanding is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302429/1198559) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40213358/1198559) answers:

**IF** you **do not use** `shouldComponentUpdate` or any other lifecycle methods (like `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate`, and `componentDidUpdate`)  where you compare the old and new `props`/`state`

**THEN**

It is fine to mutate `state` and then call `setState()`, otherwise it is not fine.

Comment: Note this only applies to the current and past versions of React (currently at v15.3.2). Who knows whether your code will break in a future version, since it's relying on behaviour that is documented as being forbidden.