# React's setState(), data mutation for nested structures, why not modify state directly?

Tags: reactjs

**Is the following react code wrong ?**

```
state={ foo: { bar: true } }  // line 1
setState(state)               // line 2   
state.foo.bar = false         // line 3
setState(state)               // line 4
```

**If yes, why ?**

[This](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) suggest that it is wrong, but does not explain why ?

**I think it is not wrong**, for the following reason:

- at `line 2` `vdom1` is created
- at `line 4` `vdom2` is created
- `vdom1` and `vdom2` are compared
- difference is propagated to the actual DOM

If this is the case, then mutating `state` at `line3` should not have any effect on what happens at `line4`.

In other words:

this should be equivalent code:

```
state={ foo: { bar: true } }  // line 1
setState(state)               // line 2   
state={ foo: { bar: false } } // line 3
setState(state)               // line 4
```

**Is this code equivalent to the one above ?**

If not, why not ?

Comment: This seems related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: I put a bounty to this related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: This is related too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300547/is-it-a-good-practice-to-modify-a-components-state-and-then-call-setstatethis?rq=1 but does not give an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an immutable clone of state is a good idea because of the way state changes are compared in order to optimise rendering.

In lifecycle methods like `shouldComponentUpdate`, `nextProps` are passed in and can be compared to `this.props`.

If you mutate the state directly, then `nextProps.prop1` and `this.props.prop1` will always be the same and therefore you might not get the expected behaviour.

I'm sure there are other reasons as well, but this one seems like the most straight-forward.

Comment: So if I don't use `shouldComponentUpdate` then there is no problem ?

Comment: There are other lifecycle methods that also can be used to compare props (like `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentWillUpdate`, and `componentDidUpdate`).  And it should be noted that you may not use these *now*, but want to use the *later* when things get slow.

Comment: So if I don't use any lifecycle methods then it is fine, but otherwise if I want to compare new and old state/props (anywhere) then I cannot directly mutate state. Right ? I mean, it depends on what I do. If I don't compare old and new state/props myself, then it's just fine, react will never want to compare old and new state/props itself, right ? So react has no hidden magic by default that tries to compare old and new state. Right ?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that the React internals make use of this.  the vdom or diffing algorithm could assume that the state is not the same as well.

Comment: Ok, interesting ! Thanks !